# controlling a java program from another

Tags: java

I want to run a Java program from another using `ProcessBuilder`

I used the code

```
Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c cd C:\\Users\\naman\\Desktop & java CalculateSum");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));
BufferedWriter output= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(pr.getOutputStream()));
String line = null;

while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

output.write("10");
output.write("30");

while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
```

CalculateSum has following code:

```
System.out.print("Enter 1 st value : ");
a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
System.out.print("\nEnter second number : ");
b=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
System.out.println("\nresult is : "+(a+b));
```

My basic motivation is to run a Java program from another Java program.

**NOTE**: I don't want to use command line arguments to take input. Also I have tried using `ProcessBuilder` for the same purpose, but that also did not work.

Comment: What is the question? Please add actual question to the... question.

Comment: Run a Java program using another Java program!!?? What for dude ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Why do you need this? How about sockets programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ExpectJ (http://expectj.sourceforge.net/) to talk to another program using standard input/output.

Use this instead of trixing with `BufferedReader`/`BufferedWriter` in your first code block:

```
ExpectJ expectinator = new ExpectJ(5);
Spawn shell = expectinator.spawn("cmd /c cd C:\\Users\\naman\\Desktop & java CalculateSum");

// Talk to it
shell.expect("Enter 1 st value");
shell.send("10\n");
shell.expect("Enter second value");
shell.send("30\n");
```

Comment: In the example given above, I have the source code so I can edit it with http://expectj.sourceforge.net/

But in reality I don't have the source code.
All I have is the code to access another program.

Comment: Wait, what code *do* you have? The client (first in your question) or CalculateSum?

Comment: So, what I suggested was to use ExpectJ in the *first* code block (see edit), *not* the second (which was CalculateSum). I think it could really work!

Answer (score 0):

Just blindly guessing at what the issue is, the problem may be flushing.

Try adding `System.out.flush();` after each print in the CalculateSum.

In the first program, add newline to your output.write calls, such as `output.write("10\n");`, and also `output.flush();` after that.